# Probability theory - Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

to avoid inmates becoming close friends, they are put into groups where they end up with other inmates.

In how many ways can the prison warden divide 6 inmates into

a) two equally large groups? b) two groups (equally or different group sizes)?

I understand that the inmates can be divided into say: group A and group B and that 3 specific inmates in group A is equivalent to putting the same 3 in group B, thus ''double-counting''.

There should be an easy way to apply this to a formula but I can't seem to get it right, any suggestions??

the answers are:

a) 10 b) 31

thanks on beforehand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ${ 6 \choose 3}$ ways to pick three from six. This equals 20. But then we double count (we could also have picked the three remaining ones, and get the same essential division. So we get half of 20.

To get all divisions, consider all splits: 1 vs 5: pick 1 from 6, so 6 ways.

2/4 split: pick 2 from 6, so ${6 \choose 2} = 15$.

So in total 6 + 15 + 10 (from the 3/3) equals 31.

Note that we can distinguish the different 2/4 splits by the people in the smallest group say, so we get different divisions for all choices of 2 people.

Comment: brilliant stuff Henno, dank je wel!!!

Comment: @WOLFOFWALLSTREET Brilliant it is not, but glad to help!